# DAX measure not working when RLS is turned on - Join paths are expected to form a tree

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI, I have the following error for a measure when RLS is turned on (this error does not show when RLS is off):

```
Join paths are expected to form a tree but the table has two join paths
```

[image]

These are the relevant relationships in the model:

[image]

I have an inactive relationship. This inactive relationship is used in the measure with the problem. But as it is inactive, I would have thought it wouldnt be an issue?? The measure is:

```
TTipsInvs =
VAR SalesValue =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( ANSAPBICustomerTransDetailed[Outstanding] ),
        USERELATIONSHIP ( 'ANSAPBICustomerTransDetailed'[SiteID], ANSAPBISites[Site ID] )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( SalesValue ), 0, ( SalesValue ) )
```

Any way to avoid this issue when RLS is turned on?

Cheers for all help

Comment: Do you really need that relationship? why not use the Bridge table,CustomerandAgent?

Comment: I need to summarize ANSAPBICustomerTransDetailed[Outstanding] by ANSAPBISite[SiteID], ANSAPBICustomerTransDetailed table contains column SiteID but CustomerAndAgent does not. Is there any other function in DAX I could use which would let me use the active relationship but group by Site.SiteID?

Comment: Then why are you conecting the Site to Customerandagent if it doesn't have site in it? Looks more like you need to change your model to reflect your business logic correctly

Comment: I need to report on Sites by Customer too, in the same report. A Customer can own one/many Sites, a Customer can have one/many CustomerTransactions. I need to report Customer Transactions by Site as well as by Customer, and I need to report Sites by Customer also. Hope that makes sense? Its a pain, but is what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TTipsInvs =
VAR SiteID =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( ANSAPBISites[Site ID] ) )
VAR SalesValue =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( ANSAPBICustomerTransDetailed[Outstanding] ),
        TREATAS ( SiteID, 'ANSAPBICustomerTransDetailed'[SiteID] ) )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( SalesValue ), 0, ( SalesValue ) )
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works and why USERELATIONSHIP() doesn't with RLS? Does it have to do with how context is applied? This answer solved my issues as well, but I would love a deeper explanation of what is going on.

Comment: My interpretation is that Row Level Security is creating a direct path using the table relationships.  So, when USERELATIONSHIP() is added, that can sometimes cause a circular reference that wouldn't exist if RLS was not on.

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding: RLS is in an always on state when used, so it is always actively using the typically active physical relationships. When trying to calculate a measure with USERELATIONSHIP, those physical relationships cannot be deactivated to avoid the circular reference because they're in use and RLS takes precedence for security. Kind of like a "file in use" lockout. Is that about right?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to @user9824134's answer that unfortunately did not have much of an explanation (cannot edit).

Why `TREATAS`:

- The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/treatas-function) explain that this function applies the result of the first argument (`clientID`) on the column in the second argument (`'ANSAPBICustomerTransDetailed'[SiteID]`)

Why this works:

- Not too sure how RLS enforces the joint path, but the "always-on" idea explained by @asp8811 makes sense to me.
- The `TREATAS` is essentially working as an alternative to `CROSSFILTER` in this case. By applying the filter of `clientID` on the `SiteID` column of the `ANSAPBICustomerTransDetailed` table, it is emulating `CROSSFILTER`.
- I'd have to test efficiency, but I suspect performance should be similar as `VALUES` already only returns a distinct list.

The below approach also works and is much shorter. The `CALCULATETABLE` expression does nothing if a filter is not passed to it, so simply using `VALUES` is enough.

```
TTipsInvs =
VAR clientID = VALUES ( ANSAPBISites[Site ID] )
VAR SalesValue =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( ANSAPBICustomerTransDetailed[Outstanding] ),
        TREATAS ( clientID, 'ANSAPBICustomerTransDetailed'[SiteID] ) )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( SalesValue ), 0, ( SalesValue ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Did a quick test:
And this looks to work without the need of enabling or disabling relationships.

[image: Model]

Before RLS:
[image: Before RLS]

After RLS:
[image: After RLS]

Comment: Hi @mxix, from Site to CustomerSite is a 1:1 relationship, not 1:M - a Customer can have many sites, but a site only has one customer record. Because of this I cannot actually activate the relationship you outlined above. Any ideas?