# DAX : Need a replacement of SWITCH due to Resource Memory Exceeds

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax, daxstudio

Background:

I have to switch between 55 measures and 16 dimensions at the same time in the query. My main query is:

```
MetricMeasure:=
CALCULATE( <Selected Measure>,
                         USERELATIONSHIP( Interface[Values],    <Selected Dimension>    )
)
```

in the above query, measure and dimension need to change in accordance with the selection on the report shown below.
[image]
Problem: This functionality is working fine with few measures and a few dimensions but with 55 measures and 16 dimensions my code is becoming 900 lines for code.

Example Code of MetricMeasure with 2 measure and 2 dimensions looks like this.

```
MetricMeasure:= 
SWITCH (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Master_Dimension[Dimension] ),
    "Age Group", CALCULATE (
        SWITCH (
            SELECTEDVALUE( DIM_metric_center[Metric] ) ,
            "Total Overtime Cost", FACT_Payroll[Overtime],
            "Total Payroll Cost", FACT_Payroll[Total Payroll Cost],
            BLANK ()
        ),
        USERELATIONSHIP ( Interface[Values], Master_Age_Group[Age Group] )
    ),
    "Company", CALCULATE (
        SWITCH (
            SELECTEDVALUE( DIM_metric_center[Metric] ) ,
            "Total Overtime Cost", FACT_Payroll[Overtime],
            "Total Payroll Cost", FACT_Payroll[Total Payroll Cost],
            BLANK ()
        ),
        USERELATIONSHIP ( Interface[Values], DIM_company[LCC Code] )
    )
)
```

Error Message: 
[image]

Any suggestion, how can I change the code in a way to use a nested Switch for 55 measure and 16 dimensions combination.

Comment: What version of SSAS?

Comment: Two inputs: (1) depeding on which version you are working, you can try Calculation Groups because they would replace the need of your switch. (2) if you need such a complex implementation maybe you are over-engineering the solution. There is always a clever and simpler implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I came across [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55744321/dax-measure-not-working-when-rls-is-turned-on-join-paths-are-expected-to-form) recently and think the `USERELATIONSHIP` to `TREATAS` refactoring might work for your situation too.

I haven't tested it but it might look something like this:

```
MetricMeasure :=
VAR Dimension =
    SWITCH (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( Master_Dimension[Dimension] ),
        "Age Group", CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( Master_Age_Group[Age Group] ) ),
        "Company", CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( DIM_company[LCC Code] ) )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SWITCH (
            SELECTEDVALUE ( DIM_metric_center[Metric] ),
            "Total Overtime Cost", FACT_Payroll[Overtime],
            "Total Payroll Cost", FACT_Payroll[Total Payroll Cost],
            BLANK ()
        ),
        TREATAS ( Dimension, Interface[Values] )
    )
```

Comment: That didn't work. The syntax is incorrect as Treatas expects table expression in the first argument.

Comment: Ah, maybe that's why the post I linked wrapped `VALUES` in a `CALCULATETABLE`. I'll update the measure with that.